# Spirit QI parser end eom

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

My data is defined as:

```
std::string data("START34*23*43**");
```

My grammar:

```
"START" >> boost::spirit::hex % '*'
```

Question:
How to parse end of message that has two stars?

https://wandbox.org/permlink/oDYjbBDb8fy79zQV

Comment: What do you want to happen? What do 2 stars mean? What does one star mean, anyways?

Comment: Two stars mean end off message. So we have begin. Payload (data) seperated by stars and end off message mark (two stars). So basically i want only accept  "START34*23*43**" and reject everything else

Comment: @sehe So someting like this:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ecc5462a8dc0081

Comment: That's the art of asking questions well! I extended my answer with an UPDATE showing just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not immediately clear what you are asking. Assuming you just want to "ignore" (or accept) trailing asterisks, here's your culprit:

```
if (first != last) // fail if we did not get a full match
    return false;
```

Just removing those lines does the trick:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40ae94cdbfc58c3b)** (note greatly simplified):

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Iterator>
bool parse_numbers(Iterator& first, Iterator last, std::vector<unsigned>& v) {
    return qi::phrase_parse(first, last, ("START" >> qi::hex % '*'), qi::space, v);
}

int main() {
    for (std::string const data : {
             "START34*23*43",
             "START34 * 23 * 43",
             "START34 * 23 * 43 *",
             "START34 * 23 * 43**",
             "START34 * 23 * 43* *",
         })
    {
        auto f = data.begin(), l = data.end();
        std::vector<unsigned> v;

        if (parse_numbers(f, l, v)) {
            std::cout << std::quoted(data) << " Parses OK: " << std::endl;

            for (auto i = 0u; i < v.size(); ++i)
                std::cout << i << ": " << v[i] << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        }
        if (f != l) {
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: "
                      << std::quoted(std::string(f, l)) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"START34*23*43" Parses OK: 
0: 52
1: 35
2: 67
"START34 * 23 * 43" Parses OK: 
0: 52
1: 35
2: 67
"START34 * 23 * 43 *" Parses OK: 
0: 52
1: 35
2: 67
Remaining unparsed: "*"
"START34 * 23 * 43**" Parses OK: 
0: 52
1: 35
2: 67
Remaining unparsed: "**"
"START34 * 23 * 43* *" Parses OK: 
0: 52
1: 35
2: 67
Remaining unparsed: "* *"
```

### Alternatively

If you actually want to ignore adjacent ** but still continue parsing, then the useful change would be to say `-qi::hex % '*'` instead of `qi::hex % '*'` which simply makes the `hex` optional.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87b08d0791bf41dc)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Iterator>
bool parse_numbers(Iterator& first, Iterator last, std::vector<unsigned>& v) {
    return qi::phrase_parse(first, last,
            ("START" >> -qi::hex % '*'), qi::space, v);
}

int main() {
    for (std::string const data : {
             "START34**23*43",
             "START34 * 23 * 43**",
             "START*******",
             "START*******1 BOGUS",
         })
    {
        auto f = data.begin(), l = data.end();
        std::vector<unsigned> v;

        if (parse_numbers(f, l, v)) {
            std::cout << std::quoted(data) << " Parses OK: " << std::endl;

            for (auto i = 0u; i < v.size(); ++i)
                std::cout << i << ": " << v[i] << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        }
        if (f != l) {
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: "
                      << std::quoted(std::string(f, l)) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"START34**23*43" Parses OK: 
0: 52
1: 35
2: 67
"START34 * 23 * 43**" Parses OK: 
0: 52
1: 35
2: 67
"START*******" Parses OK: 
"START*******1 BOGUS" Parses OK: 
0: 1
Remaining unparsed: "BOGUS"
```

> In this case you might want to re-assert that all input is parsed with `>> qi::eoi` (which beats checking the iterators manually), see [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88b17c09b675d6bc):
>
> ```
> "START34**23*43" OK: 
> 0: 52
> 1: 35
> 2: 67
> "START34 * 23 * 43**" OK: 
> 0: 52
> 1: 35
> 2: 67
> "START*******" OK: 
> "START*******1 BOGUS" Failed
> ```

## UPDATE

To the updated question in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661013/spirit-qi-parser-end-eom?noredirect=1#comment109079114_61661013):

> @sehe So someting like this: coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ecc5462a8dc0081 – [user3314011](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3314011/user3314011) [19 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661013/spirit-qi-parser-end-eom?noredirect=1#comment109079114_61661013)

You need a negative look-ahead to exclude `**`:

```
"START" >> (qi::hex % (qi::lit('*') - "**")) >> "**"
```

Actually, let's add some expectation points (`>` instead of `>>`):

```
    try {
        return qi::parse(first, last, "START" > (qi::hex % (qi::lit('*') - "**")) > "**" > qi::eoi, v);
    } catch (qi::expectation_failure<Iterator> const& ef) {
        std::ostringstream msg;
        msg << "Expected " << ef.what_ << " at " << std::quoted(std::string(ef.first, ef.last), '\'');
        throw ParseError(msg.str());
    }
```

Now you can some decent error messages too:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0debde5a01379df)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct ParseError : std::runtime_error {
    ParseError(std::string msg) : std::runtime_error(std::move(msg)) {}
};

template <typename Iterator>
bool parse_numbers(Iterator& first, Iterator last, std::vector<unsigned>& v) {
    try {
        return qi::parse(first, last, "START" > (qi::hex % (qi::lit('*') - "**")) > "**" > qi::eoi, v);
    } catch (qi::expectation_failure<Iterator> const& ef) {
        std::ostringstream msg;
        msg << "Expected " << ef.what_ << " at " << std::quoted(std::string(ef.first, ef.last), '\'');
        throw ParseError(msg.str());
    }
}

int main() {
    for (std::string const data : {
             "START34*23*43",       // Fail no EOM
             "START34 * 23 * 43",   // Fail spaces
             "START34*23*43*",      // Fail no EOM
             "START34*23*43**",     // OK
             "START34*23*43**1",    // Fail extra number
         })
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted(data) << " -> ";

        auto f = data.begin(), l = data.end();
        std::vector<unsigned> v;

        try {
            if (parse_numbers(f, l, v)) {
                std::cout << " OK:";

                for (auto i : v)
                    std::cout << " " << i;
                std::cout << "\n";
            } else {
                std::cout << "Not matched\n";
            }
        } catch(ParseError const& pe) {
            std::cout << "Error: " << pe.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Printing:

```
"START34*23*43" -> Error: Expected "**" at ''
"START34 * 23 * 43" -> Error: Expected "**" at ' * 23 * 43'
"START34*23*43*" -> Error: Expected "**" at '*'
"START34*23*43**" ->  OK: 52 35 67
"START34*23*43**1" -> Error: Expected <eoi> at '1'
```

---